# Amazon ECS support for --shm-size in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, shared-memory, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS) in order to run a dockerized webdriver (Selenium) Grid. According to [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) github page, we need to either add some `shared memory` or `mount a volume` to the docker container if we want to run long running tests using the chrome browser on the [selenium-node-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome-debug/) image.

On my EC2 instance, when I do a

```
df -h
```

I see that `/dev/shm` exists and has `3.7Gb of available free space`. But if I mount the volume to my chrome-node container using the `-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm` property, the browser is not even coming up when I run a test. But if I mount the parent `/dev` directory, tests seem to run for a few seconds and then I get the "Unable to reach Browser exception" because the browser is then getting closed (I was able to confirm this through VNC Viewer). This makes me realize that mounting a volume through ECS interface / api is not gonna help.

If I directly start docker without going through the ECS route by passing the `--shm-size` property like

```
docker run --shm-size=2500m ....
```

The tests seem to run without any trouble.

But, [ECS clearly does not support the `--shm-size`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/502) property as of now. So how to fix or work around this issue and still use ECS to pass the `--shm-size` property? Is avoiding the usage of ECS the only way here or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

Add below (EntryPoint) command as the last line in your dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT shm_dir=/dev/shm;umount $shm_dir;mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=*<size eg. 500m,1Gb>* shm $shm_dir  && /bin/bash
```

I have tested this change in *local docker*, although it requires `--privileged` or at least `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN`. I have yet to test it on AWS.

Comment: Doesn't work in ECS Fargate at least because the container cannot run in privileged mode